# How can I make all forwarded emails go into a designated folder?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I use my own Gmail but get forwards from someone else. I would like to automatically take emails that I get forwarded from that person and put them in a folder. Any help?

Answer (score 5):

That's as simple as creating a Gmail filter:

> Matches: **to:(thatotheremailaddress@gmail.com)**
>   Do this: Apply label "The Label I Want"

There are a couple of different paths you can take, but this is probably the simplest:

1. Go to Settings and choose "Filters". At the bottom of your list, click on "Create a new filter".
2. In the "To:" field, enter the email address that the messages are sent to. Click "Create filter with this search"
   [image: filter step 1]
3. Check "Apply Label" and choose the label you want to use. Then click "Create filter"
   [image: filter step 2]

(Remember: Gmail has labels, not folders.)

You can learn more about Gmail filters at [Gmail help: Using filters](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579).

I have a number of email addresses that forward to my main address, and this is how I handle them (with some minor variations).

Comment: To add to the answer above, to emulate "putting emails in a folder" it can be a good idea to also select "Skip the inbox (Archive it)". That way, the emails are not stored in the main inbox, while you can click on the label (emulating the folder) to bring them up.

Comment: Adding to the good answers above, you can use *nested* labels to further emulate a typical folder structure.